# Can I use a steam engine to extract items from chests or automatic crafting tables?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-buildcraft

The [BuildCraft wiki](http://minecraftbuildcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Minecraft_Buildcraft_Wiki) is rather light on information, but I need to know: is it possible to use a steam engine to extract items from chests or automatic crafting tables without the engine blowing up? If so, how?

Comment: If you mean running an item from a cobblestone generator, for example, and running it through a chest, and then through an automatic crafting table, yes it's possible. There are a few guides on youtube if I remember correctly, although I've personally never tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wooden pipes extract items from chests (and perhaps automatic crafting tables; I haven't tried). Engines can then be attached to the wooden pipe.

I recommend watching the videos on the [official YouTube channel](http://www.youtube.com/user/SpaceToadCraft) to gain a basic, working knowledge of the mod.

Comment: Yes, they will work with auto-crafting tables also, but using this setup, they will explode after a while.

Comment: @John — I've never had that problem. Are you connecting more than one engine to the pipe?

Comment: No, I'm not.  Which type of engine do you use?  I use redstone engines.

Comment: If you have not done so already, I would recommend updating to 2.2 and upgrading your engines. Redstone engines are the weakest, and overheat easily. A combustion engine combined with a cooling source will solve the exploding problem. A steam engine should work as well, as long as you use more than one.

Comment: @Domocus: redstone engines work the best when they are overheated, they won't explode

Answer (score 0):

A wooden pipe powered by a redstone engine is all you really need to extract items from chests or auto crafting tables.  Using a combustion or steam engine on a wooden pipe is kind of overkill, and I don't think it makes the pipe extract items any faster.  And unlike the other engines, redstone engines will never explode so they don't need cooling.